# Websraping in R

Tags: r

I am trying to web scrape news data into R. I am trying to search the html that I downloaded to find keywords in each line/row. So if a row in the page starts with
"" I want the number of the row/line and then later isolate that line and row.

```
library(rvest)
googlenews<- html("https://news.google.com/")
grep("</div",googlenews)
**Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'**
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant rvest

Comment: So are you trying to find out where all the divs are?

Comment: Read `?selectorgadget` to see how to use `rvest` properly. You use a tool called selector gadget to find which parts of the website you want to scrape.

Comment: By the way, `html()` is deprecated. You should be using `read_html()`.

Answer (score 2):

To learn how to scrape data from websites using `rvest`, you should read the documentation on [Selectorgadget](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html), a Javascript tool that identifies parts of the website that you want to scrape.

If you want to simply grab all the `div` layers on a website (which can be a ***lot***, since websites can have hundreds and hundreds of divs...), you can do the following:

```
library(rvest)

# Get the site
googlenews <- read_html("https://news.google.com/")

# Grab all the div layers
divs <- html_nodes(googlenews, "div")

# Look at how many div layers you grabbed
length(divs)

[1] 2120

# Get the text from the first couple of divs
html_text( head(divs) )

[1] "Search Images Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive More »Settings | Sign in"
[2] "Search Images Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive More »"                  
[3] "Settings | Sign in"                                                       
[4] ""                                                                         
[5] ""                                                                         
[6] ""
```

However, you are really scraping more than necessary by just searching for `div`s. You should use the Selectorgadget to get the CSS code for the specific parts of the website that you want to scrape.