# Coercing HTML into a Dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to web scrape news data into R. I am trying to search the html that I downloaded to find keywords in each line/row. So if a row in the page starts with
"" I want the number of the row/line and then later isolate that line and row.

```
library(rvest)
googlenews<- html("https://news.google.com/")
grep("</div",googlenews)
**Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'**


as.data.frame(googlenews)

Error in as.data.frame.default(googlenews) : 
  c("cannot coerce class \"c(\"HTMLInternalDocument\", \"HTMLInternalDocument\", \"XMLInternalDocument\", \" to a data.frame", "cannot coerce class \"\"XMLAbstractDocument\")\" to a data.frame")
```

How do I coerce the html object into a data-frame?

Comment: Why not follow up in the question you already asked? This is an almost word by word replication of your old question, which I provided an answer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295855/websraping-in-r

Comment: Coercing to a data frame imho makes no sense. You can coerce it to a character vector by using `as(googlenews, "character")`. But for what you are looking for, I'd just replace `html()` by `readLines()`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you pretend that `html()` (or `read_html()`) returns a simple character vector on which you can use `grep()` - that is not the case.

If you want to use rvest's power use it via `html_nodes()` and `html_text()`:

```
googlenews <- read_html("https://news.google.com/")
nodes <- html_nodes(googlenews, "div")
html_text( nodes )
```

... if you want to handle the HTML file as simple text use something like:

```
googlenews <- readLines("https://news.google.com/")
grep("</div",googlenews)
```

For something like `as.data.frame(googlenews)` to work somebody must have written a function that turns the one class into the other. For the tree representation you get using rvest this is not trivial and hence does not exist. For rvest there are excellent package vignettes, examples, blog posts - you should really have a look at those.